# How to restrict user inputing dot before typing but allowing after

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a specific validation which allows user to only type numbers, decimal numbers but restrict user typing any symbols at all.
At the moment y logic allows user to type only numbers, decimal numbers but I need to restrict user to be able to type dot in the beginning.

Here is my logic:

```
event.target.type=="example" && !(/^\d+$/.test(event.key)) && event.key!="."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: don't forget to handle cases where the user pastes content in one chunk as well. Don't just validate on keypress, or it will be easy to bypass your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\d+(\.\d)?\d*$
```

explanation

- ^\d+ - first input must be a digit only
- (.\d)? - optional dot following by a digit
- \d*$ - digits also

does not match:

.1
1.
1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer `^\d+(\.\d+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/zC7y16/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```